# React - How to avoid object getting same key? - Todo

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a todo app. The problem is: when I add two todos for example, first one gets id 0 and the other one gets id 1 (this is from todo.length), if I remove the first one (id 0) and add another one, it will create another todo with id1 which already exist. How do I prevent this?

I'm thinking maybe useEffect that is checking/updating the todo so it always the correct length.
But i'm not really sure how to implement this (i'm still learning), advice would be appreciated

This is the code & sandbox link so you can test code https://codesandbox.io:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([])
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("")

  function handleDescriptionChange(event) {
    setDescription(event.target.value)
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    setTodo([...todo, {
      id: todo.length,
      task: description,
      complete: false,
    }])
    setDescription("")
  }

  function handleDeleteButton(id) {
    setTodo(todo.filter(todo => todo.id !== id))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="todo">Add todo: </label>
        <input type="text" value={description} onChange={handleDescriptionChange} required/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todo.map((todo, index) =>
        <li className="todo-item" key={todo.length}>Todo {todo.id}: {todo.task} {todo.complete.toString()}
        <button onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(todo.id)}>Remove</button></li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Have a nice one guys

Comment: You need to wrap the li and the button into a fragment for example and set the key in that fragment

Comment: @mgm793 that will create an invalid DOM nesting, as button will be inside `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something else instead of the length as `id`. Create a separate state variable `counter` (which you will increase each time you assign it to `id`) for example and use that, or use library like this: [shortid](https://github.com/dylang/shortid).

---

Also I think you have a typo and  you meant `todo.id` instead of `todo.length` here:

> key={todo.length}

Answer (score 0):

React key works differently , as you are specifying id as the length of todo you should aspect that id should always return unique values always and the todo list you are mapping needs a unique key so that react can change its state and re rerender only if the key is changed but in your case react rerenders every time you add or delete todos that's not good approach as you can use Nano Id or generate unique or random token and use a react fragment for passing key id.

```
    import React, {useState} from "react";
    
    
    export default function App() {
      const [todo, setTodo] = useState([])
      const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
      model.id = nanoid() 
      function handleDescriptionChange(event) {
        setDescription(event.target.value)
      }
    
      function handleFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
    
        setTodo([...todo, {
          id: model.id,
          task: description,
          complete: false,
        }])
        setDescription("")
      }
    
      function handleDeleteButton(id) {
        setTodo(todo.filter(todo => todo.id !== id))
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Todo App</h1>
          <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="todo">Add todo: </label>
            <input type="text" value={description} onChange={handleDescriptionChange} required/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul className="todo-list">
            {todo.map((todo, index) =>
<React.Fragment>
            <li className="todo-item" key={todo.length}>Todo {todo.id}: {todo.task} {todo.complete.toString()}
            <button onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(todo.id)}>Remove</button></li>
<React.Fragment>
)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Always use a unique `id` for `key`

Well, you can use `key={index}`

```
<ul className="todo-list">
        {todo.map((todo, index) =>
        <li className="todo-item" key={index}>Todo {todo.id}: {todo.task} {todo.complete.toString()}
        <button onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(todo.id)}>Remove</button></li>)}
</ul>
```

Comment: Using index as a key here is not going to solve the issue since the list is dynamic, i.e. items are added and removed from it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: React docs: "We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state."